# ImportError for Nonexistent File in Django's Main Branch After Working on Separate Branch

Tags: python, django, git, branch, importerror

I'm encountering an `ImportError` in my Django project involving branch management. Here's what I did:

1. **New branch**: In a branch named `test-new-spider`, I created and committed a file named `spider_base.py`, which includes a class `SpiderStores` and a new command to run the spiders.
2. **Switching to Main Branch**: After committing these changes in the `test-new-spider` branch, I switched to the main branch, which does not include the `spider_base.py` file, as the changes were not merged.
3. **Issue in Main Branch**: Now, when trying to run the spider in the main branch, I encounter the following error:
   ImportError: cannot import name SpiderStores

This is confusing because `spider_base.py` does not exist in the main branch; it's only in the `test-new-spider` branch where it has been committed.

I deleted some files that were generated as eggs and logs, thinking they might be causing conflicts or stale references.

I disconnected from the virtual environment to ensure that there were no environment-specific issues contributing to the problem.

I searched for any instances of spider_base and SpiderStores in the main branch to confirm that it indeed doesn't exist there.

Comment: Do you have any .pyc files in that repo?

Comment: Huge thanks dude. I deleted it, and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete any `.pyc` files in the folder. `.pyc` files can create this issue.

It is also common practice to add `.pyc` files to the `.gitignore` file.